# DB2 Provider .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, db2

I am trying to get latest DB2 driver for .NET Core . According to the documentation below the latest version 3.1.0.200 is on Nuget but when i go to Nuget the latest driver i can see is  1.3

Documentation Link:
https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/blogs/michelle-betbadal1/2020/04/29/getting-started-with-ibm-net-provider-for-net-core?CommunityKey=f2e5dc34-896d-4e8e-9678-724907c4b9f5&tab=recentcommunityblogsdashboard

Nuget Link
https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/

Has anyone be able to download the latest DB2 driver for .NET Core?

Comment: @RoarS. Then sorry for the missleading information. I've deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

On page which you provided there is a comment:

> (...)
>
> we stopped publishing to NuGet repository and latest
> packages are available only on IBM downloads. Please refer to
> following blog for download information
> https://community.ibm.com/community/user/hybriddatamanagement/blogs/vishwa-hs1/2020/07/12/db2-net-packages-download-and-configure
>
> (...)

It sounds that you have to use IBM downloads.